# Loop to Insert new Carousel Item with 3 Cards with Offset in Wordpress

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 to create a Carousel that slides through a Card Deck with 3 Cards per Deck.  I have two queries created, one that sets up the first Slide with the active class, and the second that is supposed to create 2 more slides.  Because I am using Wordpress, I used the built in loop to create the queries and then offset the second query by 3 items.  In the second query, I used a counter to insert the necessary closing divs, and new opening divs to create a new slide.

My issue is, because the query returns all available items matching, and THEN does the offset, the counter is seeing all 9 items in the second query and I am getting a blank slide at the end.  I am not sure how to fix this.

Here are my current queries:

```
            <div id="mpcarousellarge" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <div class="card-deck">
                                    <?php 
                                        $args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'paradisepizzas',
                                            'post_status' => 'future,publish',
                                            'tax_query' => array(
                                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'pizzatypes',
                                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                                    'terms' => 'specialtypizzas',
                                                ),                          
                                            ),  
                                            'posts_per_page' => 3,
                                            'orderby' => 'id',
                                            'order' => 'ASC',
                                        );
                                        $paradisepizzas_query = null;
                                        $paradisepizzas_query = new WP_Query ($args);
                                        if ( $paradisepizzas_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $paradisepizzas_query->have_posts() ) : $paradisepizzas_query->the_post();
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="card border border-dark cardheight">
                                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) : ?>
                                                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
                                                <img class="card-img-top m-auto" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <div class="card-body card-text text-center">
                                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer bg-dark text-light">
                                                <h5 class="pizzafoot"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div class="card-deck">
                                    <?php
                                        $args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'paradisepizzas',
                                            'post_status' => 'future,publish',
                                            'tax_query' => array(
                                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'pizzatypes',
                                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                                    'terms' => 'specialtypizzas',
                                                ),                          
                                            ),  
                                            'posts_per_page' => 99,
                                            'offset' => 3,
                                            'orderby' => 'id',
                                            'order' => 'ASC',
                                        );
                                        $paradisepizzas2_query = null;                                      
                                        $paradisepizzas2_query = new WP_Query ($args);
                                        $rowCount = 0;                                      
                                        if ( $paradisepizzas2_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $paradisepizzas2_query->have_posts() ) : $paradisepizzas2_query->the_post();
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="card border border-dark cardheight">
                                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) : ?>
                                                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
                                                <img class="card-img-top m-auto" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <div class="card-body card-text text-center">
                                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer bg-dark text-light">
                                                <h5 class="pizzafoot"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php
                                        $rowCount++;
                                        if($rowCount % 3 == 0) {echo '</div></div><div class="carousel-item"><div class="card-deck">';}
                                        endwhile;
                                        endif; 
                                        wp_reset_query();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="position: relative!important;">
                                        <li data-target="#mpcarousellarge" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                        <?php 
                                            $args = array(
                                                'post_type' => 'paradisepizzas',
                                                'post_status' => 'future,publish',
                                                'tax_query' => array(
                                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'pizzatypes',
                                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                                        'terms' => 'specialtypizzas',
                                                    ),                          
                                                ),  
                                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                                'orderby' => 'id',
                                                'order' => 'ASC',
                                            );
                                            $mpclg_query = null;
                                            $mpclg_query = new WP_Query ($args);
                                            $num = $mpclg_query->found_posts; 
                                            $OffsetItems = $num - 3;
                                            $PostPerSlide = 3;
                                            $SlideCount = $OffsetItems/$PostPerSlide;
                                            $mpc = 1;
                                        ?>
                                        <?php if ( $mpclg_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                                        <?php while ( $mpclg_query->have_posts() ) : $mpclg_query->the_post(); ?>
                                            <?php while ($mpc <= $SlideCount) {
                                                print '<li data-target="#mpcarousellarge" data-slide-to="';
                                                echo $mpc;
                                                print '"></li>';
                                                $mpc++;
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                                    </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way to do this using Jquery.

I changed my php code to include a counter, and grabbed all items at once.  Using the counter, when the integer was 1, I inserted a new class on the card itself called "number1".  Using JQuery, I then searched for that class, and on the nearest parent matching class "carousel-item" I had it append the active class.

Here is the new PHP code:

```
<div id="mpcarousellarge" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div class="card-deck">
                                    <?php
                                        $class = '';
                                        $args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'paradisepizzas',
                                            'post_status' => 'future,publish',
                                            'tax_query' => array(
                                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'pizzatypes',
                                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                                    'terms' => 'specialtypizzas',
                                                ),                          
                                            ),  
                                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                            'orderby' => 'id',
                                            'order' => 'ASC',
                                        );
                                        $paradisepizzas2_query = null;                                      
                                        $paradisepizzas2_query = new WP_Query ($args);
                                        $rowCount = 0;
                                        if ( $paradisepizzas2_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $paradisepizzas2_query->have_posts() ) : $paradisepizzas2_query->the_post();
                                        if ( $rowCount == 1 ) $class = ' number1';
                                        else $class = '';                                       
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="card border border-dark cardheight<?php echo $class; ?>" id="<?php echo $rowCount; ?>">
                                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) : ?>
                                                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
                                                <img class="card-img-top m-auto" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <div class="card-body card-text text-center">
                                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer bg-dark text-light">
                                                <h5 class="pizzafoot"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php
                                        $rowCount++;
                                        if($rowCount % 3 == 0 && $rowCount < 7) {echo '</div></div><div class="carousel-item"><div class="card-deck">';}
                                        endwhile;
                                        endif; 
                                        wp_reset_query();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="position: relative!important;">
                                        <?php 
                                            $args = array(
                                                'post_type' => 'paradisepizzas',
                                                'post_status' => 'future,publish',
                                                'tax_query' => array(
                                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'pizzatypes',
                                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                                        'terms' => 'specialtypizzas',
                                                    ),                          
                                                ),  
                                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                                'orderby' => 'id',
                                                'order' => 'ASC',
                                            );
                                            $mpclg_query = null;
                                            $mpclg_query = new WP_Query ($args);
                                            $num = $mpclg_query->found_posts; 
                                            $PostPerSlide = 3;
                                            $SlideCount = $num/$PostPerSlide;
                                            $mpc = 1;
                                        ?>
                                        <?php if ( $mpclg_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                                        <?php while ( $mpclg_query->have_posts() ) : $mpclg_query->the_post(); ?>
                                            <?php while ($mpc <= $SlideCount) {
                                                print '<li data-target="#mpcarousellarge" data-slide-to="';
                                                echo $mpc;
                                                print '"></li>';
                                                $mpc++;
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                                    </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is the JQuery I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel-item div.number1').closest('.carousel-item').addClass('active');
});
```